# Very small simple precision and double precision float numbers representation

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers, representation

As I was trying to compute some very small simple precision and double precision floating numbers I encountered some issues.

Take a look at the following code sample:

```
public class FloatingLimits {

    public static void doSimpleFloatingLimitDemo() {
        float firstValue = 1.56F;
        float newValue = 1.0F / ((float)Math.pow(2.0D, 150));

        double doubleFirst = 2.56;
        double doubleNew = 1.0F /Math.pow(2.0D, 150);
        double doubleThird = 1.0F/Math.pow(2.0D, 589);
        double doubleFourth = 1.0F/Math.pow(2.0, 1589);

        System.out.println("float first value =" + firstValue);
        System.out.println("float new value =" + newValue);

        System.out.println("double first value =" + doubleFirst);
        System.out.println("double new value =" + doubleNew);
        System.out.println("double third value =" + doubleThird);
        System.out.println("double fourth value =" + doubleFourth);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doSimpleFloatingLimitDemo();

    }
}
```

It produces the following result:

[image: small numbers issue]

There is therefore a representation issue or a display issue! Does this have anything to do with numbers precision? The very small numbers that I could not represent with a simple float precision type (32 bits), could be represented with double float precision numbers (64) bits, but the double float also is showing limits. So what would that limit be for very small numbers? Is there a workaround for this using float and double numbers or should I necessarily use BigDecimal to solve it. If I have to use BigDecimals, is there a certain limit to BigDecimal representation as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to represents decimal numbers with arbitrary precision you have to use `BigDecimal`.

Here is a link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

The internal binary representation of float and double can introduce errors. Another possibility is to work with `int` or `long` multiply the values by a factor (10, 100, 1000 ...) and treat them as non decimal values.

Comment: thank you. Then How far can I go in using double and float numbers? Or should i drop them completely to use BigDecimal or the multiplication factors that you suggested? Thanks

Comment: You can use float and double if arbitrary precision is not needed and speed of execution is a primary needs.

Comment: OK, I see, if I was to program a 3D game I would go first for integers, unless I need more refinement in precision, then I would use float or double... BigDecimal would probably not fit this context... Thanks

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the fact that `float` and `double` are binary floating-point (indeed, 2^-589 and 2^-1589 are representable exactly in binary floating-point as long as they fit in the available range), and the paragraph to this effect in this answer is just rote. Besides, the answer implies that `BigDecimal` does not introduce errors. Try to represent 1/3 in BigDecimal.

Comment: In a 3D game there might be another motivation for using double - it has efficient support for trigonometry function such as sine and arctangent.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE)

> A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double, (2-2<sup>-52</sup>).2<sup>1023</sup>.

And if you run:

```
System.out.println(Math.pow(2.0, 1589));
```

You will see the expected result:

> Infinity

Comment: And so, that's why it gives me 0.0 as result. Thanks @assylias. Is BigDecimal the alternative?

Comment: @alainlompo if you need numbers that big, yes, or BigInteger if they are integers.